# Numpy Distutils issue with lapack

Tags: python, numpy, f2py

I'm trying to configure a setup.py file to compile a simple Fortran90 file with F2PY, but it uses LAPACK and BLAS, and I can't get Numpy distutils to include these libraries.

I *can* successfully compile the code into a .so using:

```
f2py -m picker -c picker.f90 -llapack -lblas
```

I would like my setup.py script to do the equivalent compilation. My setup.py looks like

```
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension
from numpy.distutils.system_info import get_info

blas_opt = get_info('blas',notfound_action=2)
lapack_opt = get_info('lapack',notfound_action=2)

libs = [blas_opt['libraries'][0], lapack_opt['libraries'][0]]
lib_dirs = [blas_opt['library_dirs'][0], lapack_opt['library_dirs'][0]]

ext1 = Extension(name='picker',
                 sources = ['picker.f90'],
                 libraries = libs,
                 library_dirs = lib_dirs,
                )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(name='phase',
          packages=['phase'],
          package_data={'phase':['README', 'events.dat', 'jftest/*', 'picker.f90']},
          ext_modules = [ext1]
    )
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time.